# Why? is the <file>.run.xml file generated when I typeset a LaTeX document

Tags: compiling, xml

I have a LaTeX document that lists the wines in my wine cellar.  This particular document doesn't use any features of the LaTeX language that I have not already used in several hundred other documents I work with.

However, when using TeXShop every time I run typeset to generate a PDF, another file is always generated that ends with .run.xml.  Sure I can easily delete this file but I am very curious as to why it is being generated when in so many other cases it is not generated.

Question -- what do I look for in the file for something I am doing that causes this file to be generated?

Comment: `texdoc logreq`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These files are written by the `logreq` package (often indirectly via `biblatex`) which aims to give a more robust log of requirements to automate whether to run latex again, or run bibtex etc

Comment: In most people's documents if `logreq` is loaded it will have been loaded by `biblatex`. (I don't think any other package uses it.) Also I'm not sure there are any tools that actually make use of the `.run.xml` file and its contents (maybe `latexmk`?).

Comment: @moewe does biblatex use it itself or just writes it in case it is useful?

Comment: Answer accepted!  I was including biblatex and when I commented it out then the typeset aborted.  After deleting the .aux file then everything was fine.

Comment: `biblatex` and Biber don't use the `.run.xml` data as far as I know.

Comment: just tried one.  I believe biblatex writes it.